# Listbox won't show keyboard caret when clicked on by mouse or focus programatically set

Tags: winapi, mfc

I'm using a `CListBox` with `Extended` selection.  When I click on the control, no keyboard caret is shown.  Using the up and down arrows also doesn't allow me to show the caret.  If I press tab and then shift tab, I can then see the caret.  Using `GotoDlgCtrl(&listboxCtrl)` or `listboxCtrl.SetFocus()` also don't work.

How can I get the keyboard caret to show up on mouse click or programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the mouse is not supposed to display the keyboard related UI features:

> For example, if the last input came from the mouse, [the system will hide the keyboard cues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-changeuistate). And, if the last input came from the keyboard, the system will show the keyboard cues.

To fake a change you can use:

```
PostMessage/SendMessage(hListBox, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, MAKELONG(UIS_CLEAR, UISF_HIDEACCEL|UISF_HIDEFOCUS), 0);
```

...or send it to your top-level window if you want to apply the change to all children.

Comment: Interesting.  When I click on a control using the mouse, I expect that the control has focus so that I can then use the keyboard, even if it doesn't show the keyboard cues.  That it doesn't isn't intuitive.

Comment: This "feature" was added in Windows 2000 and that is how the common controls are supposed to work. Designers sometimes gets their way even if it hurts usability.

Comment: Also if I set that control to have focus, that I can use the keyboard immediately.

Comment: What "feature" are you referring to?  Making the control not usable immediately from the keyboard when the control gets focus?  Smh.

Comment: Yes, the UI state feature that hides certain things. Windows 95/98 would always display them.